FreeRadius not loading clients from LDAP
I am trying to store and use my Radius clients in LDAP. They are defined and present in the LDAP:
$ ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.example.com -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w admin -b "dc=example,dc=com" '(&(objectClass=freeradiusClient)(freeradiusClientShortname=client1))'
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(objectClass=freeradiusClient)(freeradiusClientShortname=client1))
# requesting: ALL
#

# 192.168.10.2, clients, radius, services, example.com
dn: freeradiusClientIdentifier=192.168.10.2,ou=clients,ou=radius,ou=services,d
 c=example,dc=com
objectClass: freeradiusClient
objectClass: radiusClient
freeradiusClientIdentifier: 192.168.10.2
freeradiusClientShortname: client1
freeradiusClientType: other
radiusClientSecret: password

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1 

The LDAP module on FreeRadius is enabled and works perfectly when storing clients in /etc/raddb/clients.conf file. However, whenever I try to use a client defined in LDAP, does not find the client:
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 192.168.10.2 port 8021 proto udp
Ready to process requests

In fact, the FreeRadius server is not even querying the OpenLDAP server about the clients at all. There is not a single reference to Radius clients in the OpenLDAP logs.
The core problem seems to be that FreeRadius is not trying to request the clients from OpenLDAP. This sort of configuration should be possible according to FreeRadius documentation: FreeRadius: Using Using OpenLDAP is a Docker container
I may be missing some key configuration or a module.
